# What's wrong with my code? What is argv[1]?

Tags: c, pointers, argv

I'm trying to ask the user to type in a string so I will print the length of the string.  My code is built succeeded. However, when I entered a word and pressed 'enter', the program keeps running.  I had to enter a second word, then the length of the first string displays.  I'm confused at argv[1].  Can someone give me some tips and hint on how to fix this? Thanks in advance for your time.

Please note that I'm not allowed to use any string function.

```
   int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    char* s=argv[1];

    char input[256];
    s = input;
    printf("Please enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s\n", s);
    int str_length = 0;
    while (s[str_length] != '\0')
    {
        str_length++;
        if (s[str_length] == '\0') break;
    }

    printf("%d\n", str_length);


    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: `argv[1]` is the first command-line argument, but it isn't used at all in this code; `s` is initially set to point to it, but before the value is ever used, `s` is set to point to `input`.

Comment: I'm not really sure we understand what you want your code to do. Can you give us an example of input and output that you are expecting?

Comment: Your input can be multiple words separated by spaces? Or are you limiting this to only single word inputs?

Comment: @user2203774 do not edit your question based on the answers. it will be discontinuous. instead clearly indicate with a "EDIT:"(or similar) to indicate the change.

Comment: I figure out what went wrong w/ my code. My issue is resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`argv[]` is the array that holds your command line parameters, `argv[1]` is the first one (other than the command representation itself in `argv[0]`, of course). You assign it to `s` then immediately overwrite `s`, so it's not really needed here.

The reason you're having to enter *two* lines is the `\n` at the end of your input format. It requires whatever can match the format string followed by a newline, hence the `%s\n` is *eating* your first newline so that `scanf` has to go back for another one.

`%s` on it's own will fix that problem but introduce another one if what you're after is a full *line* of input - it will only read up to the first whitespace. For a proper line input function, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4023895/how-to-read-string-entered-by-user-in-c/4023921#4023921).

It does full line input with protection against buffer overflows and detection/cleanup of lines that were too long, something sorely missing in the `scanf("%s")` input method.

In addition, the `if` statement within the `while` is superfluous here since the `while` itself will catch the end of the string, and it makes little sense to have both `input` and `s` refer to the same array (it *would* make sense if you changed `s` at some point, but that's not happening here).

So, a variant *without* the advanced line iput function could be as simple as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char input[256];
    int str_length = 0;

    printf ("Please enter a string: ");
    scanf ("%s", input);
    while (input[str_length] != '\0')    /* Or consider using strlen() */
        str_length++;

    printf ("%d\n", str_length);

    return 0;
}
```

If you enter `Hello`, you'll see that it prints out `5` immediately. You'll also see `5` if you enter `Hello Pax`, which is one reason to choose the advanced input function (the other, very important, reason is to avoid introducing a buffer overflow vulnerability into your program).

Answer (score 2):

argv is used to pass process arguments. this means you can run your program like

```
a.out 123 abcd
```

argv[1] will already be assigned to a value of 123. you do not have to read it as you are doing now. in your current code , you are overwriting the reference of s to a new string after assigning it  with argv[1].

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX 100

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    char tmp[MAX];
    printf("Plese enter a string:\n");
    scanf("%s", tmp);
    printf("the length is %d\n", strlen(tmp));

    return 0;   
}
```

The argv and argc is another thing like this:
argv[0] = a.exe
argv[1] = 12345

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    printf("the length is %d\n", strlen(argv[1]));

    return 0;   
}
/*-------------------- Output --------------------
 > a.out 12345
 the length is 5
  ------------------------------------------------*/
```

Comment: if possible explain argv to him as well =D

Comment: argv is an array of (char*), that is to say 

    bash> a.out A B C

argc = 5,
argv[0] = a.out,
argv[1] = A,
argv[2] = B,
argv[3] = C,

Comment: it was just a suggestion on how you could edit the answer to improve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just change the `scanf` line:

```
scanf("%s", s);
```

As you have it (`scanf("%s\n", s);`), it requires a sequnce of characters ending in `\n`, then another `\n` to indicate when the input is finished.